# I want to make a message window in HTML but the javascript not work

Tags: javascript, html, debugging

I made a message window that will show a message when the user slide down the website and hide the message when the user slides up. I referenced [this tutorial](https://codeantenna.com/a/e7SdACmmPA) but it did not work as intended.

- This is my code:

```
<html>
  <body onscroll="scroll()">
    <div
      id="message"
      style="position:fixed;left:0%;top:30%;height:20%,width:5%;border-radius:10px;background-image:linear-gradient(90deg,rgba(100,255,200,0.5),rgba(100,255,255,0.5),rgba(100,255,200,0.5));box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px 5px rgba(100,100,100,50);"
    >
      <p>
        testmessage：
      </p>
    </div>

    <script language="javascript">
      function scroll() {
        //console.log("打印log日志");实时看下效果
        //console.log("开始滚动！");
      }

      var scrollFunc = function (e) {
        e = e || window.event;
        if (e.wheelDelta) {
          //第一步：先判断浏览器IE，谷歌滑轮事件
          if (e.wheelDelta > 0) {
            //当滑轮向上滚动时
            //console.log("滑轮向上滚动");
            document.getElementById("message").width = 0;
            document.getElementById("message").height = 0;
          }

          if (e.wheelDelta < 0) {
            //当滑轮向下滚动时
            //console.log("滑轮向下滚动");
            document.getElementById("message").width = 20%;
            document.getElementById("message").height = 5%;
          }
        } else if (e.detail) {
          //Firefox滑轮事件
          if (e.detail > 0) {
            //当滑轮向上滚动时
            //console.log("滑轮向上滚动");
            document.getElementById("message").width = 0;
            document.getElementById("message").height = 0;
          }
          if (e.detail < 0) {
            //当滑轮向下滚动时
            //console.log("滑轮向下滚动");
            document.getElementById("message").width = 20%;
            document.getElementById("message").height = 5%;
          }
        }
      };
      //给页面绑定滑轮滚动事件
      if (document.addEventListener) {
        //firefox
        document.addEventListener("DOMMouseScroll", scrollFunc, false);
      }
      //滚动滑轮触发scrollFunc方法 //ie 谷歌
      window.onmousewheel = document.onmousewheel = scrollFunc;
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I wonder what's wrong with my code and how could I fix it.

Thank you.

Comment: But the function `scroll` doesn't do anything...

Comment: @code it will hide the message if people slide dowm and I wonder how could let it work. According to the internet, <element onscroll="myScript"> can work when I silde the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to invoke your `scrollFunc()`

Add some height, so that it is scrollable.

```html
    <body onscroll="scrollFunc()" style="height: 5000px;">
```

Comment: The code has already include this:
<body onscroll="scroll()">
function scroll() {

Comment: So I do not know why it did not work, thank you.

Comment: @Yang yes, but `scroll` and `scrollFunc` is different thing, I ran your code before post the answer.

Comment: I truned it into <body onscroll="scrollFunc()"> but it still do not work, could you put all the code so that I can understanding what I need to change, I am sorry that I do not know what are you tried to express (I have pool English and I tried to put it into the translator but I still can not understand).

Comment: @Yang oh yes, you need to add some `height` to the body also, only change this `<body onscroll="scrollFunc()" style="height: 5000px;">`

Comment: I added them but I still do not know why it does not work. I wonder if you can **show me all of the code you write**, thank you very much.

Comment: here u go https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-ehzkrt?file=index.html